# SWI ProLog / ProbLog: Check if exactly one element in a list is true

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to make a function in ProbLog (extension of ProLog) that checks if only one of the inputs is True. As input the function will take a list of variables as argument. An XOR is not good enough in this case, because I am working with more than two arguments and I want the function to be true if and only if one of the elements in the list is True.

So for example:

```
function([X|Xs) :- code that checks if only (exactly) one element in the list is true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the Problog extension, but maybe you can simply count the true elements and check if the count is one? Perhaps using [this](http://people.sju.edu/~jhodgson/ai/accums.html) as a starting point:

```
length(List, N) :-
  length(List, 0, N).

length([], N, N).       % Second argument is the accumulator.
length([H|T], L, N) :-
    L1 is L + 1,
    length(T, L1, N).
```

You would then add a case where `L` is not incremented if `H` is not true, and in the end check if `N` is one.

```
hasOneTrueElement(List) :-
    countTrueElements(List, 1).
countTrueElements(List, N) :-
    countTrueElements(List, 0, N).
countTrueElements([], N, N).
countTrueElements([H|T], L, N) :-
    call(H),
    L1 is L + 1,
    countTrueElements(T, L1, N).
countTrueElements([H|T], L, N) :-
    \+ H,
    countTrueElements(T, L, N).
```

Comment: How do you add the case where L is not incremented and check if N is one? Because that is exactly the problem.

Comment: You just unify it with one: `N = 1`. If that fails, your predicate fails, so there is not exactly one true element in the list.

Comment: But how do you add that case where L is not incremented if H is not true. You can not use something like an if-statement, right?

Comment: Added code. By the way, please *upvote* and *accept* helpful answers!

Comment: Ah nice, thanks for the code :) But I have still one question: What if I want the function to check something like this: countTrueElements(\+a, \+b, c). Then it returns zero, while it should return 1, because only c is true.

Comment: Oh sorry I did that already, forgot to type the list-brackets. But it still returns zero when I use that.

Comment: Hmm now I seem to get another weird error: "No clauses found for '\+/1'". Why is the 'not'-operator not working anymore?

Comment: Does not make a difference :( And when I query with hasOneTrueElement([not(a), not(b), c]), it still gives 0 as output.

Comment: Did you define `a.`, `b.` and `c.` in your program?

Comment: Yes, I think there is something wrong with ProbLog, because these variables can also be probabilities. Im gonna look into that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
list_unique(List, Unique) :-
  select(Unique, List, Rest), \+ memberchk(Unique, Rest).
```

Comment: "No clauses found for 'memberchk/2'", Can i add the code of memberchk to my program, because problog does not know this function.

Comment: you can use member/2 instead of memberchk